# Ubuntu dual boot with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. For gaming I need windows, so I  planned to install windows as dual boot. I made a new NTFS partition and made a bootable windows usb using woeusb.
When I try boot from flash drive it shows invalid cluster 0. What I did wrong?

Comment: Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Did you boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode, as that will then be how it installs. It also only installs in BIOS boot mode to MBR, so partition format  and boot mode are vital and must match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single harddrve is being used.
M$ Windows needs to reside on the primary disk/partition -- C:/.
If your using a single harddrive, you need to install Windows first.
Then you can install Ubuntu - you'll be able to resize the Windows
partition to reserve space for Ubuntu.
[image]